# How to play Video on background with Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am creating program to play video. The first, I created an Activity for play Video from URL using Android `MediaPlayer` .

My issue is when Android's Home button is pressed, I want to play audio continuous (audio only), and when I back to program, Video must play continuous.

Have a solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Posts with code usually get more attention and have a better chance of receiving a response. Can you improve the quality of your question by showing us what you've done?